# Alert box redirects to another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, alert

I have a form and a form validation code. For third form when text fields are empty and submit button is clicked an alert box is displayed which prompt about missing fields which is good. But when I click ok on that alert box it disappears and current page will redirect on another page(which is not good). It have to stay on that page after alert box disappears. Only this is happening with third form not with first two forms. Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<form  name="myForm3" action="kbc.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="validate_kbc()">
    <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
    <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR" maxlength="14">
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br/><input type="reset" value="Reset">                    
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validate_kbc()
    {
    var k = document.forms["myForm3"]["MISDN"].value;
    var l = document.forms["myForm3"]["SR"].value;
    if(k == "" || l == "")
    {  
          alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
          //        document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
          //        document.myForm1.SR.focus();

        return false;
    }
    else if(!k.match(numbers))
    {
        alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
        document.myForm3.MISDN.focus();
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!l.match(numbers))  
    {
        alert('Please input numeric characters only in SR field');  
        document.myForm3.SR.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;    
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection dbConnection =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/portal" ,"root" , "123");
    Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String misdn=request.getParameter("MISDN");
    String sr=request.getParameter("SR");
    int i=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO kbc(MSISDN,SR) VALUES('"+misdn+"','"+sr+"')");
    out.println("Updated!!!!");

 %>
```

Comment: Does it go to kbc.jsp ? when you click OK on the alert box.

Comment: yes @lansen it does and saves an empty record in DB !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `onsubmit="return validate_kbc()"` and remove `else = return true;` from the function. The input is either false and the function will give a warning or there is no false input and the input of the form will be prosessed by the kbc.jsp

I hope this will work otherwise look at: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: The function validate_kbc only has to respond when the input of the form is false. Your function responds both when input is false and when input is true. So try to remove the else = return true statement